# Spatie assignRole not working (Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo::sync())

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-permission

Spatie user role permissions not working

```
Here is my RoleController.php

use Spatie\Permission\Models\Role;
use Spatie\Permission\Models\Permission;
public function saveUserRoles(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'role_name' => 'required|string|unique:roles,name',
        ]);
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            alert()->error(trans($validator->messages()->all()[0]));
            return back();
        }
        $role = new Role;
        $role->name = $request->role_name;
        $role->guard_name = config('auth.defaults.guard');
        $role->save();
        alert()->success(trans('New Role Created Successfully!'));
        return redirect()->route('admin.add.user.roles');
    }
```

User Model

```
User.php
use Spatie\Permission\Models\Role;
use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    use SoftDeletes, HasApiTokens;
    use HasRoles;
protected $fillable = [
        'user_id', 'profile_image', 'name', 'email', 'address','phone','location','role_id','auth_type', 'password','status'
    ];
protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
public function role()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class, 'role_id');
    }
}
```

UserController

```
UserController.php

use Spatie\Permission\Models\Role;
use App\Http\Requests\UserCreateRequest;
public function saveUser(UserCreateRequest $request)
{
$user = User::create([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'password' => Hash::make($request->password),
            'role_id' => $request->role_id,
            'status' =>0,
        ]);
        $role = Role::find($request->role_id);
        $user->assignRole([$role->name]);
}
```

When i try to create a new user it shows an error
**BadMethodCallException

Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo::sync()**

Here only need role option without any permissions

[image]

Comment: Are you assigning multiple roles to a user or a single role?

Comment: Only single role

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Here is your solution, as given in the [documentation](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v5/prerequisites#content-must-not-have-a-role-or-roles-property-nor-a-roles-method).

Comment: Is there any way to check logged user is admin or not, like isAdmin() or isUser() using spatie roles

Comment: You can do that by writing your own logic... you can do auth()->user()->hasRole('admin'); 

It will return a boolean.

Or you can write a method in your User model

 public function isSuperAdmin(): bool
    {
        return $this->hasRole('superadmin');
    }

Comment: already tried using if(Auth::user()->hasRole('admin')){ .... }

Comment: Yes, that would work too. Cheers.